# Old Material Guidelines Website

Tags: material-design

The new material guidlines website is weird. It has like generic rules but applied to weird system like "crane system" or "shine system". It doesn't show the generic rules applied as base. By show I mean with exact dp measurements. It shows the exact dp measurements with respect to the application of these rules onto another design system.

The old one ( like 2 months old) I liked because I could one to one copy it, it showed the generic rules applied exactly in dp.

Is the old website accessible somewhere?

https://material.io/design/components/buttons.html#implementation

Comment: Realize too that the new guidelines do in-fact have *new* guidelines. The old guidelines site and the new site will provide different information in various situations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access the old website here https://material.io/archive/guidelines/

Comment: Total perfection!!! How did you find that?

Comment: A couple days ago I tried to download the Material Sticker Sheet for Adobe XD, and it redirected me to that page. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

The new one still shows the exact dp measurements.

For example: https://material.io/design/layout/spacing-methods.html#spacing

You can also access some of the old content from the [Internet Time Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20180315194132/https://material.io/)...

Comment: Thanks, the wayback machine isn't loading the old components site. :( Its coming out unstyled. :(

Comment: Use what you've learned from Material guidelines and find your own standards. There are more frameworks out there

Comment: I'm a developer, when I get into design I get major choice paralysis. :( So many options.